# My parameter is suddenly not defined in 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, indexof

For some reason my function parameter 'string' is defined until it gets to the 'indexOf' method, then suddenly the console it reporting it as undefined. It works fine in the rest of the statement, I just don't get it. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function checkRoomForItem(string) {
 for (let i = 0; i < db[0].rooms[roomLoc].roomInvent.length; i++){
  if (db[0].rooms[roomLoc].roomInvent[i] === string) { 
   console.log("String is " + string);
   inventory.push(string);
   db[0].rooms[roomLoc].roomInvent.pop(db[0].rooms[roomLoc].roomInvent.indexOf(string));
  };
 };
 displayOut();
 teleTyperOutBox("you get " + string);
}
```

Comment: is `string` referenced somewhere, then passed to `checkRoomForItem` and then changed in `displayOut()`?

Comment: it's just the parameter name I used if that's what you mean, and doesn't appear anywhere else. The inputted string is broken down through several functions on the way, but at this point it is just one word as a string. If that's what you mean, I'm a bit of a noob.

Comment: Do you have any global variable called `string` defined somewhere?

Comment: No I don't, I will change parameter name out of interest, just to see if anything happens.
EDIT: just tried, made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem, I was using 'pop' incorrectly, I needed to use 'splice'.